# Git не переключается и не показывает ветки

Tags: git, git-branch

[image]

Объясните, почему вот эта вещь не хочет переключиться на ветку **master** или, хотя бы, показать список веток!

Переименовать так же не вышло

```
$ git branch -m master
error: refname refs/heads/develop not found
fatal: Branch rename failed
```

Comment: Посмотрите для начала, какие ветки есть командой `git branch --list`

Comment: Не показывает. Ничего абсолютно. Я пробовала - l, - - list, list, git branch, git branch master, git checkout master, и еще много чего. Обычно, когда хоть одна ветка, пусть даже мастер, показывает с коммандой **git branch** хотя бы ее. На любых других проектах гит работает, а на этом отвалился

Comment: @Elizaveta, удалось разобраться с проблемой?

Answer (score 1):

Такое ощущение, что у вас что-то случилось с папкой `.git/refs/heads/`.

В ней должны быть файлы на каждую существующую ветку. Имя совпадает с именем ветки, содержимое 41 байт - sha-код коммита и перевод каретки.

А файл .git/HEAD долже содержать ссылку на один из файлов в упомянутой выше папке.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `$git checkout -b "имя ветки"`. Вы создадите новую ветку и переключитесь на неё

Comment: это по-прежнему не решило вопрос( теперь я не могу переключиться обратно, та же самая ошибка

Answer (score 0):

1. можно проверить наличие ветки в удаленном репозитории `git branch --all`,  `git branch -a` или в используемой VSC
2. синхронизируйте локальные ветки с удаленными при помощи `git fetch`
3. переключитесь на нужную ветку `git checkout <branch>` (master, либо main)

P.S.: не так давно начал отвечать на вопросы в stack overflow
надеюсь, это было кому-нибудь полезно

Answer (score -3):

В папке с проектом удалить папку .git (скрыта).

После чего:

- git init  (инициализировать);
- git add . (довавить все файлы);
- git checkout -b 'name branch' (добавить ветку);
- git remote add origin 'url repository' (подключиться к репо);
- git push -u origin 'name branch' (запушить).

Меня всегда такая схема не подводила.